# Use AVAudioRecorder metering to make triangular wave

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, waveform

I am trying to make triangular waves for audio recorder through metering. I am using AVAudioRecorder this means that Fast Fourier Transformation will not work in this case (Secondly i don't have enough knowledge how to implement it). I found [this project](https://github.com/kevinzhow/Waver) on github. In this project author is using the following equation to make smooth sine wave:

```
CGFloat y = scaling * self.maxAmplitude * normedAmplitude * sinf(2 * M_PI *(x / self.waveWidth) * self.frequency + self.phase) + (self.waveHeight * 0.5);
```

If you consider this `sinf(2 * M_PI *(x / self.waveWidth) * self.frequency + self.phase)` part of equation you will find that it is the equation of sine wave ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave)). If i replace this part with the equation of triangular equation ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave)) it still make sine wave with little difference. I want to transform this equation in such a way that it make triangular wave instead of sine wave.

My triangle wave equation looks like this:

```
CGFloat t = x / self.waveWidth;
CGFloat numerator = sinf( (2.0 * M_PI * (2.0 * self.amplitude + 1.0) * self.frequency * t) );
CGFloat denominator = (2.0 * self.amplitude + 1.0) * (2.0 * self.amplitude + 1.0);
CGFloat multiplyer = (8.0 / pow(M_PI, 2.0));
CGFloat result = multiplyer * (numerator / denominator);
```

Then finally y position is calculated by:

```
y =  (result * scaling * self.maxAmplitude * normedAmplitude) + (self.waveHeight * 0.5);
```

Animation is also look unnatural. Output of this equation is:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Wait so you want to generate a triangle wave according to the microphone input (input frequency, amplitude, etc)? What is waveWidth in the equation you are basing this off?

Comment: If you look in the code 'Waver' you will find that waveWidth is equal to the width of the view.

Comment: Just want to clarify, you have already tried putting in a triangle wave but you're still getting a sine wave shape?

Comment: Yess! but the amplitude of the wave become smaller.

Comment: This is a wild shot but what happened when you increased the amplitude? And can I see your triangle wave equation?

Comment: See my updated question.
If i increase the amplitude manually it does make any notable difference.

Answer (score 2):

Well by looking at the equation you're using (which is the fourier transform), you're implementing it a bit wrong (k samples should be increasing but you've left it constant with `2.0 * self.amplitude + 1.0`. You're also leaving out `(-1)^k` which adds in the odd harmonics.

Wikipedia wrote this:

> It is possible to approximate a triangle wave with additive synthesis by adding odd harmonics of the fundamental, multiplying every (4n−1)th harmonic by −1 (or changing its phase by π), and rolling off the harmonics by the inverse square of their relative frequency to the fundamental.

I'm guessing (as I'm not a DSP expert) that because you're leaving the k value as a constant it is just giving you a sine wave output.

Look at this algorithm block for the triangle wave (try it, then change it for your code):

```
phaseIncr = (2.0 * M_PI / sample_rate) * self.frequency;
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
    triVal = (phase * 2.0/M_PI);
    if (phase < 0) triVal = 1.0 + triVal;
    else triVal = 1.0 - triVal;
    sample = amplitude * triVal;
    if ((phase += phaseIncr) >= M_PI) phase -= (2.0 * M_PI); 
}
```

I also see that the original project wrapped the phase in `setLevel` method so check that out. Hope this helps out and let me know if this doesn't work, I'll try to help as much as I can.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Did you try to implement the above algorithm in the sample project? I will also post gif of my output.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Sorry I didn't get a chance to do it, but if you still need help implementing it I'll try it from my side, just been busy !